# How to write an "ß"?

Tags: writing, eszett, handwriting

What is the proper way to write an *Eszett* on paper with a pen? In English we are told to start letters at the top, but the *ß* only has ends at the bottom, so what is the proper way to draw the letter?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In German there is not a single "proper" way to write letters in handwriting. There are regional variations (see [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ausgangsschrift) for details).

For schools in Germany there are federal regulations that define how pupils learn to write. Most widely used are the *["Lateinische Ausgangsschrift"](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:La-ges.jpg&filetimestamp=20060501153550)* and the *["Vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift"](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Vereinfachte_Ausgangsschrift.png&filetimestamp=20071016122745)*. In these the letter *'ß'* is written as follows:

#### "Vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift":

[image]

#### "Lateinische Ausgangsschrift":

[image]

Comment: What is the english word for 'Unterlänge'? Upvoting for the underlength! :)

Comment: If "Unterlänge" means the part of a letter which extends below the line, you use "descender" in English.

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that `ß` does not have an uppercase form. Instead it's substituted with `SZ`. **Edit:** Whoops, [obviously I'm not up-to-date about that](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Gro.C3.9Fschreibweise).

Comment: @Bobby Using *SZ* must be really old style. 40 years ago I already learned to use *SS* instead. Just as *ss* is used in lower case if you don't have a ß on your ancient typewriter.

Comment: @Takkat, in addition to regional variations even the way I learned to write some letters 40 years ago is different from what pupils learn nowadays in the same region.

Answer (score 25):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: scharfes S ß how to write]

Comment: I hate it when my customers say that, because it means they didn't understand what I wrote. But +1 for the answer ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost I don't get it. Could you draw a diagram please? ;-)

Comment: Yes, and I will make it *direktorensicher*.

Comment: The first one looks like a capital B, no 'Unterlänge'. No + from me. :(

Comment: @user_unknown: The first word is written in blockletters ("Druckschrift"). No "Unterlänge" required in a blockletter ß.

Comment: @userunknown: I suggest the addition of a writing sample of the word *Buße*, to indicate the contrast between *B* and *ß* ;)

Answer (score 14):

```
   ^
  |  \
  |   )
/||  <,
 ||   )
.||..'..............the line...
 ||
 \/
```

Somehow like that. It depends - as always - how the previous letter ended, and what the next letter is.

Answer (score 13):

I just write it like my greek beta

```
2--
|  \
|   )
|  3
|  \
|   )
|  4
1
```

There are some people writing it with an upstroke (quite similar to user unknowns proposal) like that: 
[image: ß (sz) stroke order]
[taken from WikiBooks German](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Q&A#How_do_you_write_.3C.C3.9F.3E.3F)

Other variants, which are no more/not yet teached in Germany, are from the [Schulausgangsschrift](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulausgangsschrift) (left) and the proposed [Grundschrift](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundschrift) (right)

[image: ß (sz) Schulausgangsschrift and Grundschrift]