# Why does Gauß' signature have no ß?

Tags: handwriting, writing, eszett

I do not speak German but during a discussion with some German friends we ended up chatting about the evolution of the way German is written (I am French and I mentioned some changes we went through too). It was mostly around ß→ss, ö→oe, ü→ue, ...

Sometime later I happened to look at the German Wikipedia page about [Carl Friedrich Gauß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gau%C3%9F) and to my surprise, **there is no ß is his own handwritten signature**. What is at the end does not look like [the handwritten version one can expect](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/how-to-write-an-%C3%9F).

[image]

Is there an explanation for that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Gauss’s signature on Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Signatur_Carl_Friedrich_Gau%C3%9F.PNG) does not use an *ß* ligature because it is written in roman script, and an *ß* ligature in roman script did not yet exist at the time.

Historically, German *ß* [originated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Origin) **in blackletter type** (or handwriting based thereupon like [kurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent)) as a ligature of [long *ſ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) and *ʒ,* the blackletter form of *z.* This ligature only existed in [blackletter type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter) (e.g. [fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur)), but not in [roman type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_type).

There was no *ß* when German was written **in roman type** (or handwriting based thereupon like [round hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_hand)), which became increasingly common since the late 18th century. Instead, the blackletter type *ß* was often imitated by using roman type *ſs,* even after long *ſ* had become uncommon in roman type around 1800. Alternatively, simple *ss* could also be used (a usage that has persisted in Switzerland). Another option, *sz,* was propagated by the Grimm brothers, but it never caught on (neither did their use of small letters). The roman type ligature *ß*  was only introduced in a 1876–1902 spelling reform.

In [Gauss’s correspondence](https://gauss.adw-goe.de/handle/gauss/551), we can observe that he used different signatures:

- When signing in blackletter script, he used *ß,* cf. letters like [Carl Friedrich Gauß → Johanna Gauß, Braunschweig, 1804 Juli 12](https://gauss.adw-goe.de/handle/gauss/1832) or [Carl Friedrich Gauß → Franz Baumann, Göttingen, 1830 Dez. 14](https://gauss.adw-goe.de/handle/gauss/7716).
- In some roman script signatures, he used *ſs,* cf. letters like [Carl Friedrich Gauß → Carl Ludwig Harding, Braunschweig, 1806 Febr. 15](https://gauss.adw-goe.de/handle/gauss/573) or [Carl Friedrich Gauß → Peter Andreas Hansen, Göttingen, 1854 März 27](https://gauss.adw-goe.de/handle/gauss/536) (roman script signature after blackletter script letter).
- In other roman script signatures, he used *ss,* cf. letters like [Carl Friedrich Gauß → Carl Ludwig Harding, Braunschweig, 1803 Juli 26](https://gauss.adw-goe.de/handle/gauss/547) or [Carl Friedrich Gauß → Carl Ludwig Harding, Braunschweig, 1804 Febr. 3](https://gauss.adw-goe.de/handle/gauss/551) (roman script signature after blackletter script letter)

Comment: You write Gauss with ss, in your links and in most publications it is Gauß. Is there a reason you prefer this variant?

Comment: @mtwde: It is because I am from Switzerland.

Answer (score 16):

Historically, the "ß" [originated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Origin) from a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature) between two originally separate letters.

There are two important ligatures to mention: One is the ligature between a "[long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)" and a lowercase "z". The "long s" was a letter that isn't used anymore. It looked a bit like a lowercase "f". This part of the origin of "ß" can still be found in the letter's name, "Eszett".

The second ligature that went into the "ß" is a ligature between a long s and a lowercase "normal" s. This part of the origin of "ß" can still be seen in the letter's shape:

ſ + s becomes ß (the long s isn't diplayed here very well)

And those two letters, ſ and s, seem to be what Gauß wrote in his signature.

Comment: Ha, this is interesting, I did not realize that ß was a ligature but now that you pointed it out it is quite clear (both letters combine nicely to an ß)

Comment: Note that English, and most other European languages, used the ſ at the time as well. It still exists as the modern integral sign. The normal s was used as well, but generally only at the ends of words.

Comment: Wrong, **German** ß did not originate from an ſs ligature, but from a blackletter ſʒ ligature. Like the Wikipedia article you have linked to explains.

Comment: @mach The answer does.acknowledge that ſʒ is also often mentioned. The Wikipedia article makes it much more complex than you seem to imply. Also, the Gauſs signature clearly ends with a cursive s.

Comment: @VladimirF: The answer begings by explicitly declaring that the historical origin of ß was a ſs ligature. That is wrong.

Comment: @mach The Wikipedia page that you are talking about: "Thus, the modern (Antiqua) German letter ß is in some fonts derived from ſs graphically although it represents the historical ſʒ digraph continued from Middle High German and Early Modern High German orthography."

Comment: @VladimirF: What origin does the answer make claims about? The graphical origin of ß or its historical origin?

Comment: @mach I do not unterstand what you are after. In some typefaces it both historically (how else for dog's sake?) and graphically originated in ſs while representing the old historical  ſʒ digraph. Anyway, the letter Gauſs has in his signature is clearly an s.

Comment: @VladimirF: I do not understand what you are after either. Sure, when you add a restriction like “[i]n some typefaces”, then the assertion would no longer be wrong. But there is no such such restriction in the answer, which makes its assertion wrong.

Comment: Technically, you're both right, as _both_ ligatures went into what we know as "ß". To quote the aforementioned Wikipedia article: "It originates as the ⟨sz⟩ digraph as used in Old High German and Middle High German orthography, represented as a ligature of long s and a 'tailed z' (...) in blackletter typefaces (yielding ſʒ), which became conflated with the ligature for long s and round s (ſs) used in Roman type." I edited my answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 4):

You wrongly assume, that handwriting rules and conventions were unmodified since Gauß, which is not the case.

For a start you may look in [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F), especially the section  *Lateinische Schreibschrift*.

Gauß used a quite usual way writing *ß* for that period.